# Remove border between cells in html/css

Tags: html, css

Can somebody help me? I'm trying to remove/hide border between table cells, but fail. Here's CSS I've tried to do this:

```
table, td, tr{
    border-style: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

and here's my HTML:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>HI</td>
      <td>HI</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>HI</td>
      <td>HI</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and I'm still getting this:

[image: Picture]

Comment: Image is not useful in this case, Put your html code if you want more help.

Comment: `<style>
table, td, tr{
border-style: hidden;
background-color: white;
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing: 0px;
}
</style>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>HI</td>
<td>HI</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>HI</td>
<td>HI</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>`

Comment: I'm using the same code Here  https://jsfiddle.net/h9o205d5  and i don't get the border. You may have another css rules which affect it

Comment: Yes, you should definitely show us other CSS or try to find it yourself because your HTML doesn't contain any inline-styles and is displayed adequately with this CSS. I suggest you to use DOM-inspector to check which element(s) have borders.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Answer (score 0):

Try using **border: none**

Also, right click on one of the cells and choose "Inspect Element" (in Firefox). Then on the right side of the new window (under Rules) you can see from where the border is coming (CSS).

Also be sure that you don't have any margin between the elements so that a possible background color from an element behind it could shine through. But that should be not really possible when using a table.